# Do I still owe Epic royalties if I am not enrolled in the Unreal Engine subscription?

Tags: legal, licensing, unreal-4

I have just started using Unreal Engine 4 and I have had a very good experience, though I have left the subscription now.

I've made an Android game with it and I am planning to release it, but I have some doubts about the license. Suppose I post my game on my own website for, say, $%, will I still have to give 5% of my income to Epic? How will they come to know that the game is made in Unreal Engine?

I am very confused in taking this step and I'm not really understanding what they mean by "5% gross revenue."

Comment: Whether or not Epic can "know" your game is using the engine is largely irrelevant (but there are ways to do so, both from a technical perspective and simply by knowing that the engine behaves in certain ways and looks a certain way, in general). You agreed to the license, and thus you are bound by it if you continue to use their product. Don't try to skirt the law.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, and you should seek out an actual lawyer for a proper legal consultation.

That said, the terms of the [license](https://www.unrealengine.com/eula) seem pretty clear. You may cancel your subscription, at which point you are not entitled to future updates of the engine, but you can still use the version you have:

> After cancellation of your Subscription by either you or Epic, you
>   will not be entitled to access or use future Versions of the Engine
>   Code or Assets that Epic makes available under the License. However,
>   cancellation of your Subscription will not affect your rights under
>   the License with respect to any Licensed Technology you have already
>   downloaded under the License.

However, your use of the existing version is still bound by the terms of the license, which further states that:

> You agree to pay Epic a royalty equal to 5% of all worldwide gross
>   revenue actually attributable to each Product, regardless of whether
>   such revenue is received by you or any other person or legal entity...

Thus, you still need to pay Epic the royalties you agreed upon the release of your game regardless of whether or not you are still paying for the subscription. This applies for all forms of distribution, including self-hosting the game and selling it from your website. Failure to pay Epic on time will result in late fees being incurred, and possibly eventual legal action.

The license spells out the particulars of the royalty arrangement, including when you have to pay them and when you don't. "Gross revenue" is *not* your profit, it is the total amount of money your product generates before subtracting out other third-party cuts, refunds you may need to issue, et cetera. The license even gives an example:

> The royalty is based on gross revenue from end users, regardless of
>   whether you sell your Product to end users directly, self-publish via
>   App Store, or work with a publisher. The following simplified example
>   illustrates the application of the royalty to gross sales: if your
>   Product earns $10 on the App Store, Apple may pay you $7 (having
>   deducted 30% as a distribution fee), but your royalty to Epic would
>   still be 5% of $10 (or $0.50).

Comment: Epic knows the rule, "always negotiate on the gross." Hollywood accounting makes net income/profit easily reduce-able to zero, so if they didn't insist on Gross they shouldn't really expect to get paid anything ever. +1 especially for pointing out how this effects things like app store %s

Comment: Suppose I distribute  my game for free but include in game purchases in that game, will I still have to pay them 5%?

Comment: @TanayKarnik: The quotes in Joshs post answer your question, but you got to read them. E.g. "The royalty is based on gross revenue from end users", and "if your Product earns $10 on the App Store, Apple may pay you $7 (having deducted 30% as a distribution fee), but your royalty to Epic would still be 5% of $10 (or $0.50).". If your game generates X Dollars , whether or not on Apple Store or whatever, and disregarding how much you get from X Dollars, the royalty is still based on X Dollars.

Comment: @phresnel actually it's if the player pays X then you owe Epic 5% of X

Comment: @ratchetfreak: That's what I implied with "if your game generates X Dollars". Is saying "to generate" not common in English?

Comment: @phresnel "if your game generates X Dollars" could be easy taken as "if I get X dollars from Apple/Google/whoever for my game". It is important that the 5% are on the money the customer pays!

Comment: @Josef: I see. Language fail on my side :)

Comment: Could you please explain the part in the license about no royalty on the first $3,000.00 in gross revenue per calendar quarter, specially the part that says "per calendar quarter". For instance if one game has a revenue of $2000 in the first quarter, $4000 in the second quarter, and then $1000 in the third, do I need to make only one payment for 5% of $4000 in the second quarter? ...great answer.

Comment: @rraallvv You're correct; that's covered later in the actual license (I didn't quote it above): "Within 45 days after the end of each calendar quarter in which a Product earns revenue outside of the above-listed royalty exclusions, you must pay to Epic the full amount of the royalty due for that quarter and send Epic a royalty report on a per Product basis."

Comment: @JoshPetrie Thanks for the clarification, I'm gonna give the license a full read now that back in my laptop.